# Exception when starting a ServiceHost with NamedPipe

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-xp, named-pipes

I've an application that self-host a WCF service(to allow another application to pilot the application).

The service was working fine on all our tests computers(Windows 7, Windows XP), but one of our customer(on windows xp) just called us reporting an exception at the launch.

With our software trace we found the following:

It seems that when we do the `ServiceHost.Open` call, we get this exception:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested address is not valid in its context
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpUtility.BindSocket(Socket socket, IPEndPoint localEndpoint)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpUtility.CreateListenSocket(IPAddress ipAddress, Int32& port, Int32 receiveBufferSize, Int32 timeToLive, Int32 interfaceIndex, Boolean allowMulticastLoopback, Boolean isLoopbackAdapter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpChannelListener.InitSockets(Boolean updateListenPort)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpChannelListener..ctor(IUdpTransportSettings settings, BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpTransportBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener[TChannel]()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncodingBindingElement.InternalBuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener[TChannel]()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.MaybeCreateListener(Boolean actuallyCreate, Type[] supportedChannels, Binding binding, BindingParameterCollection parameters, Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, ServiceThrottle throttle, IChannelListener& result, Boolean supportContextSession)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildChannelListener(StuffPerListenUriInfo stuff, ServiceHostBase serviceHost, Uri listenUri, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, Boolean supportContextSession, IChannelListener& result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnBeginOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
```

I looked a little bit on this error, and it seems it can be related to a wrong IP provided.

First, here is how we create our service:

```
m_host = new ServiceHost(m_ourServiceInstance);
NetNamedPipeBinding namedPipeBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
namedPipeBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
SetBindingDefaultTimeouts(namedPipeBinding);
String url = String.Format("net.pipe://localhost/ServiceName_{0}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
m_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IOurServiceType), namedPipeBinding, url);
m_host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
m_host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
m_host.Open();//Crash on this line !!!
```

Several mysteries for me:

1. Why does this use socket for local NamedPipe?
2. What can change between different computers here? Except the process id I don't see?
3. What can I do to investigate more ? I'm a little lost here.

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue, but the service name having the suffix of process_id is .. "weird to me".  Your clients need to be able to find your services.....  and this code gives you a different servicename each time.          "net.pipe://localhost/EmployeeService"  ,   "net.pipe://localhost/ServiceName_EmployeeService"     that would be more common IMHO.   How does your client wire up to this exposed service (since the process_id fluctuates) ?

Comment: In fact: Let's say that the application hosting the service is the application "A". The application that connect to this service is the application "B". The application B is in fact the application which is starting the application "A" and then use the WCF service to configure a lot of parameters of the application A

Comment: Looks like somebody took out the "Self" of "SelfHost".  I don't understand that move at all.

Comment: This is kinda of a question and observation. Why is security being set on named-pipes?  What could intercept that message on a localmachine talking to a local-machine?

Comment: @granadaCoder : You'are totally right, I don't see any valid reason to use this here. I will see with the creator why it has put this security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does this use socket for local NamedPipe?

Because you have `UdpDiscoveryEndpoint` here:

```
m_host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
```

> What can change between different computers here? Except the process id I don't see?

1. An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
2. you have already the same qualified address (maybe from previous process that not disposed properly it's unmanaged resources . or not shutdown yet)
   for more info: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: What about access permission? I don't think for the 2), because we always with this specific computer, even after a fresh restart.

Comment: i think your problem is in 'UdpDiscoveryEndpoint' . try to remove this line of code and check it again. maybe the problem is you do not set a URL for it

Comment: Yeah, I also think that this is the part that create trouble, seeing the call stack. We do not currently need it(but soon we will). So first I'm gonna to deploy a new build to our customer without this to see if it's the issue. But I will need it soon, so I'm very interessted to know what can cause trouble with that. How should I set an url for it?

Comment: i have no more ideas what exactly happened in there, i recommend you check this out for more info how to use discovery service, goodluck! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483326.aspx